# Proving $\gcd(n^2(n^2+1),2n+1)=\gcd(2n+1,5)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We suppose $\forall n \in \mathbb {N}\setminus{0}$.

How can I prove that $\gcd(n^2(n^2+1),2n+1)=\gcd(2n+1,5)$?

Comment: Since $n^2$ and $2n+1$ are coprime, the $n^2$ on the lhs can be dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(2n+1)^4 - 16n^2(n^2+1) & = 32n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n+1\\
4(2n+1)^3 - (32n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n+1) & = 40n^2+16n+3\\
10(2n+1)^2 - (40n^2+16n+3) & = 24n+7\\
12(2n+1) - (24n+7) &= 5
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\gcd(n^2(n^2+1),2n+1) & = \gcd(32n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n+1,2n+1)\\
& = \gcd(40n^2+16n+3,2n+1)\\
& = \gcd(24n+7,2n+1)\\
& = \gcd(2n+1,5)
\end{align}

Comment: You mean Euclid's algorithm: divide them and carry on with the remainder..

Comment: @Berci Yes.${}{}$

Comment: The gcd is unchanged if we multiply $n^2(n^2+1)$ by any power of $2$. Now division by $2n+1$ is straightforward.

Comment: @Marvis Could you please show the quotient and remainder and can the power of 2 wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

$\rm mod\,\ {2n\!+\!1}\!:\ \color{#C00}{2n\equiv-1}\,\Rightarrow\,16(n^4\!+\!n^2)\equiv (\color{#C00}{2n})^4\!\!+4(\color{#C00}{2n})^2\!\equiv (\color{#C00}{-1})^4\!\!+4(\color{#C00}{-1})^2\!\equiv\, \color{#0A0}5,\ $ therefore

$\rm\qquad (\color{#C00}{2n\!+\!1},\color{#0A0}5)=(2n\!+\!1,16(n^4\!+\!n^2)) = (2n\!+\!1,n^4\!+\!n^2)\,\ $ by $\rm\ (2n\!+\!1,16)=1\ $ and Euclid, and

since $\rm\quad\,\ (\color{#C00}a,\,\color{#0A0}b) =\, (a,\,c) \ \ if\ \ b\equiv c\:\ (mod\ a)\ \ $ [modular gcd law, heart of Euclidean algorithm]

Comment: nice observation (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(1) For any $\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;(2n+1,5)=1\,\,\vee\; 5\,$ ;

(2) We have

$$ 2n+1=0\pmod 5\,\implies n=2\pmod 5\implies n^2(n^2+1)=4\cdot 5= 0\pmod 5\ldots$$

Comment: That shows only the easy part: $\rm\:c=(2n\!+\!1,5)\mid (2n\!+\!1,n^4\!+\!n^2)=d.\:$ The less trivial opposite direction, that $\rm\:d\mid c,\:$ also requires proof.

Comment: (1) That's your opinion, (2) Those are **hints** ...

Comment: If you believe it shows that $\rm\:d\mid c\:$ then please do explain how.

Comment: I think you're overlooking the word "hint"...and I never claimed it shows anything: it *suggests*.

Comment: Imo, if one is giving a hint to only *part* of the answer, esp. an easier part, then one should explicitly mention that. Else it could mislead the OP into thinking that nothing more needs to be done.

Comment: It that **really** misleads *a student* to believe that then (s)he has to put way more attention to what (s)he does and stop accept anything (s)he reads as last word. Many times I have the intention to make them think, not only accept what I write which, of course, can be greatly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Euclidean Algorithm, we get
$$
16n^2(n^2+1)-(8n^3-4n^2+10n-5)(2n+1)=5\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, $(n^2(n^2+1),2n+1)\mid5$.

Furthermore, since $(5,16)=1$, we have $5\mid2n+1\Longleftrightarrow5\mid n^2(n^2+1)$. Thus,
$$
(n^2(n^2+1),2n+1)=(2n+1,5)\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Where's the Euclid-Wallis table? Under the table calculations, eh?

Comment: @MathGems: I did use it, but I kept it on paper. It did not need to be copied to the answer. Things get a bit unwieldy with polynomials.

Comment: Yes, of course I was joking. In this case Gauss trumps Euclid and Bezout, since the modular approach is a one liner, but the extended gcd calculation is an order of magnitude more work (too big apparently to fit into MSE margins!) Did you ever do a polynomial example on MSE?

Comment: I have done one or two (to get Padé approximations if I remember), but I forget if it was on sci.math or MSE. It was probably on sci.math. I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/218925), but it is standard Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: It would be nice to have one protoypical example to refer to, but perhaps this one is too unwieldly. Do you see how the Bezout relation is related to the calculation that I did, and why the cubic cofactor of $\,2n+1\,$ is not really needed? I hope to find some time soon to explain further how the method in my answer works in general (non-monic factor theorem, localization, etc).